# Is kAudioFormatDVIIntelIMA actually supported on iOS?

Tags: ios, avaudiorecorder, adpcm, ima4

According to the [iOS Technology Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/MediaLayer/MediaLayer.html) the DVI/Intel IMA ADPCM format is supposedly supported.  Specifically, there is a section that indicates:

> iOS supports many industry-standard and Apple-specific audio formats, including the following:
>
> AAC
>   Apple Lossless (ALAC)
>   A-law
>   IMA/ADPCM (IMA4)
>   Linear PCM
>   µ-law
>   DVI/Intel IMA ADPCM
>   Microsoft GSM 6.10
>   AES3-2003

However, in attempting to use the kAudioFormatDVIIntelIMA format key:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
     setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord
     error: &error];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{
        AVFormatIDKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatDVIIntelIMA],
        AVSampleRateKey : [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 8000.0],
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
    };

    NSError *error;
    AVAudioRecorder *newRecorder =
    [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: soundFileURL
                                settings: recordSettings
                                   error: &error];

    NSLog(@"Recorder Errors: %@", [error description]);
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1718449215 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)
```

with kAudioFormatUnsupportedDataFormatError being 1718449215.  So what gives?

(Note that if I change this to kAudioFormatAppleIMA4, the code above works fine.  So it seems that only IMA4 ADPCM is supported, not the DVI/Intel IMA ADPCM).

Comment: How are you initializing soundFileURL?

Comment: I'm just creating a file in the temp dir.  This file gets created fine when I use kAudioFormatAppleIMA4.  So I know that the URL is fine: `NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory ();
    NSString *soundFilePath =
    [tempDir stringByAppendingString: @"sound.caf"];
    
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];`

Comment: ".caf" is not ADPCM, I think ".wav" or something else might work.

Comment: @Kicks. I got error 1718449215, too. How do you fix it?